# Why sometimes when I do not specify STAThread attribute, the code will fail mysteriously?

Tags: c#, com

When I use some 3rd party library. If I forgot to specify STAThread, the code will fail mysteriously, I want to know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing mysterious. Because the COM library is written in a wa that requires all incoming threads to be STA. Like all UI components - STA has been the UI threading model since dinniosaurs smashed the first windows back in the flintstone age.